# Are staircases more efficient than the method of constant stimuli?

Tags: signal-detection, psychophysics

A Bayesian Quest adaptive procedure ([Watson and Pelli 1983](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03202828)) is the theoretically most efficient procedure for estimating thresholds under a certain, potentially unrealistic, set of constraints. In my field a transformed up-down method ([Levitt 1971](http://scitation.aip.org/content/asa/journal/jasa/49/2B/10.1121/1.1912375])) is used much more commonly. Has any work been done comparing the efficiency of the transformed up-down method with the method of constant stimuli?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a special issue of the journal Perception and Psychophysics in 2001, titled **Psychometric Functions and Adaptive Methods**. It contains several papers relevant to your question. Klein's paper [1] references all the others and reviews what each is about. It should serve as a good starting point.

An excerpt from Klein's summary:

> 6. **The simple up–down (Brownian) staircase with threshold estimated by
>         averaging levels was found to have nearly optimal efficiency in agreement
>         with Green (1990)**. It is better to average all levels (after about four
>         reversals of initial trials are thrown out) rather than average an even
>         number of reversals.Both of these findings were surprising.
> 7. **As long as the starting point is not too distant from threshold, Brownian 
>         staircases with their moderate inertia have advantages over the more prestigious 
>         adaptive likelihood methods**. At the beginning of a run, likelihood methods may have 
>         too little inertia and can jump to low stimulus strengths before the observer is 
>         fully familiar with the test target. At the end of the run, likelihood methods 
>         may have too much inertia and resist changing levels even though a non stationary 
>         threshold has shifted.

---

[1] Klein, S. A. (2001). Measuring, estimating, and understanding the psychometric function: a commentary. Perception & Psychophysics, 63(8), 1421–55. Retrieved from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11800466